# How to preserve line breaks when generating python docs using sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I am using Sphinx for generating docs for a python project.
The output html is not preserving the line breaks which are present in the docstring.
Example:

Code

```
def testMethod(arg1,arg2):
    """
    This is a test method

    Arguments:
    arg1: arg1 description
    arg2: arg2 description

    Returns:
    None
    """
    print "I am a test method"
```

Sphinx O/P:

```
TestModule.testMethod(arg1, arg2)

This is a test method

Arguments: arg1: arg1 description arg2: arg2 description

Returns: None
```

Any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: Example needed. Restructured text format is correctly preserved by Sphinx.

Comment: Any idea on how to do this when your docstrings are in Google format and want to avoid adding a bunch of \n 's ?

Answer (score 60):

In general in restructured text use

```
| Vertical bars
| like this
```

to keep line breaks

Comment: Don't just add | on two separate lines (say if you want two line breaks)... make sure you have 2 empty spaces after the | 
So it becomes: 

|(space)(space)

for a new line.

Comment: I believe this break the html semantic. Instead of `<p>` you end up with `<div class="line">` ...

Comment: In case, someone is looking for the documentation: https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#line-blocks

Answer (score 24):

If you add the following to your main .rst file:

```
.. |br| raw:: html

   <br />
```

Then in your markup you can add in `|br|` to create linebreaks just for HTML.

```
I want to break this line here: |br| after the break.
```

From: http://docutils.sourceforge.net/FAQ.html#how-to-indicate-a-line-break-or-a-significant-newline

Comment: This works with figure captions, whereas I couldn't get the vertical bars to work.

Comment: Beware that the |br| in the text need to be surrounded by spaces.

Answer (score 20):

This answer comes late, but maybe it'll still be useful to others.

You could use `reStructuredText` in your docstrings. This would look something like

```
:param arg1: arg1 description
:type arg1: str
:param arg2: arg2 description
:type arg2: str
```

From the looks of your example however it seems you're using the Google Style for docstrings (http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pyguide.html?showone=Comments#Comments).

Sphinx does not natively support those. There is however an extension named `napoleon` that parses Google and Numpy style docstrings at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sphinxcontrib-napoleon.

To use the extension you have to append `'sphinxcontrib.napoleon'` to the `extension`-list in your Sphinx `conf.py` (usually `doc/source/conf.py`), so it becomes something like

```
extensions = [                                                                  
'sphinx.ext.autodoc',                                                       
'sphinxcontrib.napoleon',                                                   
'sphinx.ext.doctest',                                                                                                             
]
```

Comment: This was the exact answer I was looking for while trying to understand why sphinx wouldn't render the Google Style correclty although the guide lines even recommend to use Sphinx.

Comment: As of Sphinx 1.3, the napoleon extension will come packaged with Sphinx under sphinx.ext.napoleon. The sphinxcontrib.napoleon extension will continue to work with Sphinx <= 1.2.

Answer (score 13):

In my particular case, I was trying to get autodoc to read a doc string (`""" my doc string """`).  I ended up using `\n` everywhere I needed to add a line break:

```
This is the first line\n
and this is the second line\n
```

Comment: any idea on how to do this when your docstring is in Google Format?

Answer (score 12):

In your case you can write:

```
def testMethod(arg1,arg2):
  """
  This is a test method

  | Arguments:
  | arg1: arg1 description
  | arg2: arg2 description

  | Returns:
  | None
  """
  print "I am a test method"
```

Comment: This didn't work for me in Python 3.8

Answer (score 2):

See if you have enabled [*Support for NumPy and Google style docstrings*](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/napoleon.html#module-sphinx.ext.napoleon) extension in your `conf.py` file:

```py
extensions = ['sphinx.ext.autodoc', 'sphinx.ext.napoleon']
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your CSS stylesheet has padding or margins on the `p` element so that the paragraphs that Sphinx creates are visible.

In many cases, rendering issues can be fixed more easily by tweaking the stylesheet than trying to control exactly what Sphinx generates.

Answer (score 0):

I am **NOT** using Sphinx, and none of these answers worked for me.

I finally found the [answer here.](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/documentation/#preventing-rewrapping)

You just need to put `\b` alone on a line before the paragraph.  For example,

```
def testMethod(arg1,arg2):
    """
    This is a test method

    \b
    Arguments:
    arg1: arg1 description
    arg2: arg2 description

    \b
    Returns:
    None
    """
    print "I am a test method"
```

The `\b` bizarrely is actually a `backspace` character.

Answer (score 0):

The vertical bars doesn't work for me.  I use the following format instead.

```
::
    Straight Flush: (8, high card)
    Four of a Kind: (7, quad card)
```