# Line Breaks in docstring (Django Admin Documentation)

Tags: python, django, docstring

After activating admindocs in Django app, the following comment is added in an object:

```
"""
Maintains ABC Object definitions. Each ABC has one or more PQR. 
See Also :model:`myapp.PQR` and :model:`myapp.XYZ`.
"""
```

In Django Admin Documentation, it is rendered as a single line:

```
Maintains ABC Object definitions. Each ABC has one or more PQR. See Also: myapp.PQR and myapp.XYZ.
```

Is there a way to apply line breaks in comments. I'm new to python/ django.

Saw [How to preserve line breaks when generating python docs using sphinx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033239) but adding a Vertical bar ( with 2 empty spaces as well) did not work. Vertical bar also became part of the single line:

```
Maintains ABC Object definitions. Each ABC has one or more PQR. | See Also: myapp.PQR and myapp.XYZ.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to preserve line breaks when generating python docs using sphinx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033239/how-to-preserve-line-breaks-when-generating-python-docs-using-sphinx)

Comment: Vertical bar did not work.

Comment: I would just add an empty line between the lines, and not worry about it being paragraphs instead of lines with breaks. In a sense, this is better anyway: line breaks are great for code, but not really meant for text.

Comment: Empty Line worked! Thanks @Evert