# Line breaks in normal text in Sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx

I have the following text in a .rst file:

```
Some text.
* Heading
  | The first topic.
  | Another topic which is very verbose and spans multiple lines ad infinitum.
  Topic continued......................................
```

and I would like it to render as:

```
Some text.
* Heading
  The first topic.
  Another topic which is very verbose and spans multiple lines ad infinitum....................
  Topic continued.............
```

However it renders like this in Html:

```
Some text.
* Heading| The first topic.| Another topic which is very verbose and spans multiple lines ad infinitum .................... Topic continued
```

The Sphinx documentation suggests using the `|` symbol to signal a line break as do several posts here on Stackoverflow, but I have been unable to get it to work. I would like a method which is independent of the Sphinx builder being used.

Blank lines between the elements do work but do not give the visual effect that I want.

What do I need to do?

Comment: @Steve I feel that this solution is too heavyweight for my situation. I have decided to use a solution given in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033239/how-to-preserve-line-breaks-when-generating-python-docs-using-sphinx which allows me to use |br| as my marker for a line break.

Answer (score 3):

Do this in two steps.

First get your reStructuredText to use the correct whitespace to generate a usable HTML structure with default visual styles applied.

```
Some text.

* Heading

  | The first topic.
  | Another topic which is very verbose and spans multiple lines ad infinitum.

  Topic continued......................................
```

Second override the default style sheet to generate the desired visual effect as described in this SO post, [How do I set up custom styles for reStructuredText, Sphinx, ReadTheDocs, etc.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32079200/how-do-i-set-up-custom-styles-for-restructuredtext-sphinx-readthedocs-etc/32079202#32079202).

Comment: Your example will not work because | needs to be present in the first position of the line with no preceding white space.

Answer (score 2):

If you add the following to your main .rst file:

```
.. |br| raw:: html

   <br />
```

Then in your markup you can add in |br| to create linebreaks just for HTML.

```
I want to break this line here: |br| after the break.
```