# Python auto docstring with sphinx new line

Tags: python, python-sphinx, docstring, numpydoc

I am wondering how can I have a new line when generating auto documentation using Sphinx. I am not using the default Sphinx docstring format reStructuredText, but I am using the Numpydoc format. I tried using '\n' yet it makes a line break, and I only need a new line. Here is an example of a Python module ...

```
""" This is the first sentences 
| this is the second sentence at line 2 ... note that vertical bar 
| this is the second sentence at line 3 ... note that vertical bar 
...... 
def function1 (input):
    """ this function docstring starts here
    | this is not sentence number 2 at the vertical bar is not working 
    | this is not sentence number 3 at the vertical bar is not working 
    | this is not sentence number 4 at the vertical bar is not working 
"""
```

Comment: Will [line blocks](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#line-blocks) do what you want?

Comment: Thanks, the vertical bar works for module docstring, yet it didn't work for function docstring. I donot know why. I know that the line blocks based on [vertical bar is part of the restructured Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033239/how-to-preserve-line-breaks-when-generating-python-docs-using-sphinx).

Comment: Please provide examples in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add a blank line after the first line:

```
def function1 (input):
    """ this function docstring starts here

    | this is not sentence number 2 at the vertical bar is not working 
    | this is not sentence number 3 at the vertical bar is not working 
    | this is not sentence number 4 at the vertical bar is not working 
    """
```

Body elements are separated by blank lines. The docstring consists of two body elements: a regular [paragraph](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#paragraphs) and a [line block](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#line-blocks).