# Break caption in figure directive

Tags: restructuredtext

How can I break long caption in figure directive? I tried line blocks but the caption disappeared completely.

```
.. figure:: a.png
   :width: 200

   | First line
   | second line.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to preserve line breaks when generating python docs using sphinx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033239/how-to-preserve-line-breaks-when-generating-python-docs-using-sphinx)

Comment: @StevePiercy No. I tried what proposed in the first answer and it doesn't work.

Comment: You should read the other answers, like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9664844/2214933

Answer (score 0):

I you don't want an explicit breaking point but just wrap the caption so that it nicely matches the image, you can specify the :figwidth: option and let the browser do the wrapping for you:

```
.. figure:: a.png
   :width: 200
   :figwidth: 200

   A long figure caption that should
   wrap in the output.
```